# App Engine + Maven + Hot swap

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine

is it possible to run app engine with maven and have hot swap of the war dir?

Like, run my app engine maven project with "mvn appengine:devserver" and when I update index.html in my war directory and refresh in browser, it will update.

It seems like fullScanSeconds only apply to Java classes and not files in war directory.

Thanks,
Carl

Comment: It seems that the only way to force a reload is either to run a maven goal (like `mvn package`) or `touch`ing one of the `class` files.  Not great, but it's quicker than re-packaging the whole war.

Comment: Found a way! Run maven but set webapp folder as source "mvn -Ddirectory=src/main -DfinalName=webapp -DoutputDirectory=src/main/webapp appengine:devserver"